# The server committed a protocol violation The server response was: UGFzc3dvcmQ6

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

This is my code for sending email using a mail server. I researched a lot on the protocol violation error and tried everything, but it just doesn't seem to work.

```
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        try
        {
            smtp.Host = "mailserver";
            smtp.EnableSsl = false; 
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = "username";
            string password2 = Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("password"));
            NetworkCred.Password = password2;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = 587;//Specify your port No;
            smtp.Send("fromemail", "toemail", "subject",
                "body");
            MessageBox.Show("Email sent");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Email not sent " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

I also contacted the hosting company and they said that can't provide anymore in depth analysis. Hoping to find a solution here.

Please note that I'm using the actual username, password and mailserver. I just have't typed them in this question.

Comment: I think you need a real username and password. You are sending the words "username" and "password".

Comment: No I'm using the actual username, password and mailserver. I just have't typed them in this question.

Comment: I had the same problem and it's because UseDefaultCredentials needs to be set to false if you are providing your own credentials.

Answer (score 0):

UGFzc3dvcmQ6 is Base64 for the string "password". Explained very well here:
http://www.ericshalov.com/2014/12/03/what-does-ugfzc3dvcmq6-mean/

Comment: thank you for your response. If I use the base64 encoding or I use the password without it, I get the same error.